# How can I prevent Excel from formating Numbers that I import via Java?

Tags: java, excel, formatting

I´m trying to get this number: "16.233549.1008" into an Excel sheet without changing the format of the cell. But always when I import this number, Excel just writes: "162.335.491.008".
My simple code: println("16.233549.1008");

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: I don't see how doing an import into either tool would result in the decimal places jumping around like that.  Can you give us an exact reproduction of your problem?

Comment: I think Excel is formating the cells as "Number" so it automatically changes the decimal places. Is there any way to stop Excel from doing this?

Comment: Yes, but what sort of number has three decimal places?  This looks like an IP address string to me.

Comment: *"without changing the format of the cell"* What is the format of the cell?

Comment: It´s just a serial number that has to have these decimal places. I just figured out that when I attach any char at the end of my serial number it is displayed right. But there has to be another way!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is formatted as "number"

Comment: If you format the excel cell where you import that value as text, it should work. If you are using the text import wizard, you can change the type of the imported columns during the import process (as far as I can remember; it might depend on the Excel version).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: I suspect the dot is not the decimal delimiter here but the thousands separator. That would lead to that behavior. But of course the question is not clear at all, because there is nothing how one could using `println("16.233549.1008");` to put a cell value into a cell using `apache poi`.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes that could be the case. It does not matter how I get the values into the Excel sheet.. I can even copy and paste it manually and it still formats the field as "numeric"

Comment: @Manu: Please do clarifying what exactly you are doing. Are you creating an Excel workbook using `apache poi`? If so, set the cell value like `cell.setCellValue("16.233549.1008");` and set the number format of that cell to `@` = Text (see https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Data+Formats for how to). If not, then describe exactly what you are creating using `Java` code.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want to create a csv-file

for that case, i suggest to create the particular content as '`String`'-Function that makes the csv-file look like this:

```
A;B;C;D;="16.233549.1008";E;F;G
```